# How to access from outside a RabbitMQ Kubernetes cluster using rabbitmqctl?

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq

I've a RabbitMQ cluster running on a Kubernetes environment. I don't have access to the containers shell, so I'm trying to run rabbitmqctl from a local container (same image).

These ports are exposed:
- 15672 (exposed as 32672)
- 5671 (exposed as 32671)
- 4369 (exposed as 32369)
- 25672 (exposed as 32256)

The correct cookie is on $HOME/.erlang.cookie on my local container.

How to specify the cluster URL and port to rabbitmqctl, so I can access the RabbitMQ cluster from outside?

Is it necessary to expose other ports?

Is it even possible to do this, since I can't find any reference to this on documentation?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to expose ports 4369 and 25672 using the same port numbers externally as I can't think of a way to tell the Erlang VM running `rabbitmqctl` to use a different port for EPMD lookups. You should also expose [35672-35682](https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html#ports) using the same port range externally.

Since you're using Kubernetes, I'll assume that you are using long names. Assume that, within your container, your node name is `rabbit@container1.my.org`, to access it externally use this command:

```
rabbitmqctl -l -n rabbit@container1.my.org
```

Please note that `container1.my.org` *must* resolve via DNS to the correct IP address to connect to that container.

Comment: So I've to use a tcp proxy to redirect ports. I won't do this for now, since I just needed rabbitmqcli to get cluster health and partition. I'll use only HTTP Api for that. Thank you anyway!